# How to collect data about processes network activity?

Tags: windows, networking, performance, performance-monitor

Windows has `Performance Monitor` and `Data Collector Sets` feature. Apparently, it can log all system information.

I want to know, how much data, per process name, per remote IP address, was received and sent by my windows box.

Unfortunately, there are numerous performance counters and unintuitive interface. So I can't deduce how collect data I want.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Download the process explorer from [Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) which is a free and a good tool that shows you which process make an IP connection on which port.

Also download Wireshark , which is a free utility and run it to obtain the statistic of the network traffic  on network ports such as UDP, HTTP, SMTP etc..

You can connect this two statistics to see which application sends which traffic.  If you have a second computer , you can also use a [TAP](http://www.cubro.net) to look in your network connection.

Comment: I don't see any network related features in Process Explorer from SysInternals. Maybe you meant [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) from SysInternals.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) lets you view the traffic in a tree view. Top is traffic versus other traffic. Next level is the processes, for each processes all IPs are listed and for each IP all connections are listed. See the image below how that looks like.

Unfortunately I did not see how to get the number of bytes sent per process or IP or connection.

[image: Microsoft Network Monitor Screenshot]